# How to properly number paragraph according to APA style

Tags: writing, citation, paragraphs

If an article cites (Mara, 2010, “Mission,” para. 1) using APA style, does para.1 refer to first paragraph within

- the "Mission" section?
- or the whole page?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seeks guidance as to how to interpret an arbitrary set of guidelines; it does not allow for other accepted conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Para.1 refers to the 1st para under the "missions" Section

Comment: thanks for your clear and prompt reply. I greatly appreciate it!